# Multiple content types in views in order one by one

Tags: views

I have 3 content types (A, B, C).

I need to output all of them in views in order:

A1
B1
C1
A2
B2
C2
...

I need to get the last node with content type A, then the last node of content type B, then the last node with content type C, then the node of content type A created earlier etc.

So, is it possible to alternate content types in views?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Yes that is possible. If A is the name of the content type and 1 is the ID of the content. Then you first sort on ID and then on Content Type.

Comment: Thanks!
But nodes were created not in that order, so 1,2,.. are not node IDs.

So i need to get the last node with content type A, then last node of content type B, then last node with content type C, then the node of content type A created earlier etc.